# Chrome Extension Development: How to use @import url('theme.css')?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, import, content-script, css-import

How do I use`@import` css in a chrome extension? I've tried the code below, but I can't get it to work

> *some code is omitted so it's easier to read*

### File Structure

```
|-- lib
    |-- jquery.min.js

|-- theme
    |-- _import.css
    |-- theme-blue.css
    |-- theme-yellow.css
    |-- theme-green.css

|-- my-extension
    |-- my-extension.js
    |-- my-extension.css

|-- manifest.json
```

### Code

**manifest.json**

```
{
"content_scripts": [{

    "js": [
        "lib/jquery.min.js",
        "my-extension/my-extension.js"],

    "css": [
        "theme/_import.css",
        "my-extension/my-extension.css"],

    "run_at": "document_end"
}],

"web_accessible_resources":[
    "lib/*",
    "theme/*"
]
```

}

**_import.css**

```
@import url('theme-blue.css');
@import url('theme-yellow.css');
@import url('theme-green.css');
```

**theme-blue.css**

```
* { background: blue; }
```

**theme-yellow.css**

```
* { background: yellow; }
```

**theme-green.css**

```
* { background: green; }
```

Comment: I [guess](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined) `@import url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/theme/theme-blue.css');`, see also [Google Chrome extension relative path](//stackoverflow.com/a/3963210)

Comment: Tried it... No luck

Comment: Well, if there are no errors in the console then Chrome doesn't support @import in content script CSS. You can submit a bug report on https://crbug.com

Comment: Uhm, wait! Where's the [`"matches"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to specify which URLs to affect?

Comment: I omitted it from my example so it would be more clear.. haha.. so not to worry, my extension is working but the `@import` isn't